# Oracle Stored Procedure Create Temp Table from existing table

Tags: oracle, procedure

I am trying to write a stored procedure in oracle that should do a a few relatively simple things:

- create a new temporary table based upon an existing table in the database
  and
- copy records from the existing table into the temporary table based upon a where clause

I want the stored procedure to take three parameters so I can use it for tables and where clauses

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SYSTEM.COPY_TO_TEMP_TABLE(  
FROM_TABLE IN NCHAR,  
TO_TABLE IN NCHAR,  
WHERE_CLAUSE IN NCHAR  
)  
IS  
BEGIN   
    CREATE TABLE TO_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM FROM_TABLE WHERE WHERE_CLAUSE;  
END COPY_TO_TEMP_TABLE;
```

I find it hard to believe this has not been done thousands of times in the past - any ideas why this won't compile for me?

Answer (score 1):

1. Creating a table is not something one would generally do in a stored procedure.  Unlike some other databases, Oracle doesn't have local temporary tables.  If you have to create a temporary table, you'd do that at installation time when you're creating all your other tables.  The data for the temporary table is local to the session that inserts it but the definition is shared across sessions.
2. Do not create objects in the `sys` or `system` schema.  Those are reserved for Oracle.  Create a new schema for the objects you want to create.
3. It is unlikely that you want to use `nchar` parameters if you're building a SQL statement.  The SQL statement needs to use the database character set not the national character set.

If you want to do this, you'd need to use dynamic SQL.  You could do something like

```
create or replace procedure create_table( p_from  in varchar2,
                                          p_to    in varchar2,
                                          p_where in varchar2 )
as
  l_sql varchar2(1000);
begin
  l_sql := ' create table ' || p_to ||
           '  as ' || 
           ' select * from ' || p_from ||
           '  where ' || p_where;
  -- Print it out so you can debug when things inevitably go wrong
  dbms_output.put_line( l_sql );
  execute immediate l_sql;
end;
```

Note that this is doing nothing to prevent SQL injection attacks.  I'm also assuming that whatever you're passing in to `p_where` is already properly escaped so that it can just be concatenated in (i.e. `p_where` is "foo = ''bar''" rather than "foo = 'bar'").  You could obviously change that assumption and add escaping logic to the procedure.